# Wordpress edting page and custom field

Tags: wordpress, field, edit, display, web-testing

Need help in wordpress (edit page and custom field,not change in css). After editing custom field and page, the website's page didn't display the correct setup as in wordpress. I had done clear the cache but still no change in website page. No need to change in css.

[this is the editing page for contact us page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHTdW.png)

[This is my custom field setting (contact us page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFUKb.png)

But still after update the website didn't display the right template.

Comment: Have you edited the page.php template to output these fields?

Comment: But, didn't by using wordpress editing we can ignore the code in .php file? Since i'm just a beginner in wordpress, i don't want to focus on .css or .php. Every time i open the page, it will display old custom field not the new one that i created.

Comment: It looks like you are using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and with this plugin, in order to output the data from your Custom Fields you need to edit the theme files, otherwise there is no way for the theme to know where to display your data. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/